# Changing the maximum mail size in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, quota, centos6, attachment

When sending large email to a new CentOS6 server running Postfix as the MTA, the following message is returned:

> `tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of this error. The error that the other server returned was: 552 552 5.3.4 Error: message file too big (state 18)`

I found the following [suggestion](http://jacob.steelsmith.org/content/queue-file-size-limit-exceeded-postfix), but am unclear as to where it needs to be added in the `main.cf` file:

> This was caused by Postfix and it's limit on not only messages but mailbox sizes.
>
> I had to add this setting in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:
>
> `message_size_limit = 31457280`

How can the maximum mail size (including attachments) be increased in Postfix?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Add it anywhere in main.cf, it's not relevant :) But it's good to keep directives grouped in some logical manner, it is easier for maintance
According to official postfix documentation:
`message_size_limit (default: 10240000)` The maximal size in bytes of a message, including envelope information. Note: be careful when making changes. Excessively small values will result in the loss of non-delivery notifications, when a bounce message size exceeds the local or remote MTA's message size limit.

Additionally, the default mailbox size of 50M may prevent mail from being delivered, especially after increasing the permitted message size.  To increase maximum per user mailbox size, add `mailbox_size_limit = <size in bytes>` to main.cf.

Additionally, as [Ian Sparkes](https://serverfault.com/users/343117/ian-sparkes) commented, if you are using a virtual mailbox configuration, you might need to set `virtual_mailbox_limit = <size_in_bytes>`.

Comment: If you are using a virtual mailbox configuration, you might need to set

 `virtual_mailbox_limit = <size_in_bytes>`

Took me ages to find this, no one seems to talk about it. ;)

In the end if found it by invoking `postconf` and scanning for likely looking candidates.

Comment: The default message size limit is 10240000 Bytes = 10 MB, not 50 MB

Comment: @黄雨伞 - mailbox size and message size are different, and described in this answer differently

Comment: 1) 2018. 2) Giving mail sizes in byte units. WTF.

Comment: Yeah would nice if to able to do `message_size_limit=15M`  (just a suggestion, don't try this)

Answer (score 20):

Yes, you are correct: [message_size_limit](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#message_size_limit) is the configuration directive you need. Put it anywhere in the *main.cf* file and reload (or restart) Postfix.

You may use the **postconf** tool to check the currently configured value:

```
postconf message_size_limit
```

Comment: Example for setting the value: postconf -e message_size_limit=51200000

Answer (score 8):

**Be careful** if setting this limit to a high number. You need at least 1.5 times the size of `message_size_limit` of free space on the partition where the Postfix queue resides. If you don't have that free space, then **all** messages are rejected even if they are only a few kilobyte in size. And if you receive one message of this size and then the space exceeds (during final mailbox delivery) all further messages are rejected. Due to missing space.

Also note: Email is not a file transfer protocol. See this QA: [Why do we still have such small email attachment filesize restrictions?](https://serverfault.com/questions/304424/why-do-we-still-have-such-small-email-attachment-filesize-restrictions)

Answer (score 7):

Don't forget to set

```
virtual_mailbox_limit = <size_in_bytes>
```

if you are using a virtual mailbox configuration. Took me ages to find this, no one seems to talk about it. ;)

Comment: Appreciate the comment - but this would be better as a suggested edit to the existing answer and/or as a comment on it :)

Comment: You are right, I moved it. Will delete this answer.

Comment: you should delete this answer :)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for answer with recent versions of postfix(3+) , you should define `message_size_limit` to a number atleast 1.5 times higher then the actual message you want to send. Also this limit should be smaller then `mailbox_size_limit`.

For example if you want the clients/programs to be able to send a mail of atleast 30 MB in size, you have to set `message_size_limit = 47185920` i.e 45 MB considering roughly a 1.5 times size increase(as the messages are transferred mime encoded and thus size increase by some factor), i.e 30 * 1.5 =45 MB(47185920 bytes) .

Note: This [thread](https://serverfault.com/a/189510) mentions the math required for mime-encoded expansion of message by  a factor of 1.37. For safe side we can consider this 1.5 times.