# Message size exceeds capabilities of MX

Tags: postfix

One sender (`@gmx.net`) to my mailserver received an error message:

> Message size exceeds capabilities of MX responsible for the recipient

I [increased the `message_size_limit`](https://serverfault.com/questions/327416/changing-the-maximum-mail-size-in-postfix) from `10240000` to `20480000`, but I'm not sure that this will help as I thought the error message relevant to the `message_size_limit` should be `Message size exceeds fixed limit` instead. I never heard about that `capabilities of the MX`.

**Q: What does the error mean ? How to "fix" ?**

---

A Google search was of no help:

- only 17 (not helpful) results for [`Message size exceeds capabilities of MX responsible for the recipient`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Message%20size%20exceeds%20capabilities%20of%20MX%22)
- but 14.700 results for [`Message size exceeds fixed limit`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Message%20size%20exceeds%20fixed%20limit%22)

---

I use [tomav/docker-mailserver](https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver).

(Maybe) relevant configuration:

```
mailbox_size_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_limit = 51200000
```

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine that the free space of the partition of the postfix queue is not enough. I can still remember times when Docker only provided 10GB for the container partition. Depending on which configuration you are using, this could be a problem. Alternatively, `mailbox_size_limit` or `virtual_mailbox_limit` should be increased.

What exactly does `postconf message_size_limit` say?

For an exact answer, more information would be necessary, since I don't know the container, I can't go into it further.